# chosen-select duplication on triggering update

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-chosen

I'm currently trying to use chosen-select for a multi select dropdown. When I want to update the select box and display the updated selection I call this line of code:

```
$('.chosen-select').val("Campus Wired Network").trigger('chosen:updated');
```

This will then display in the input box the value, "Campus Wired Network".

If I try and do the same thing programmatically:

```
$('.chosen-select').val(array[0]).trigger('chosen:updated');
```

I get the value displayed twice, so "Campus Wired Network" and then the same again "Campus Wired Network" within the select box.

I posted this questions yesterday which shows my full code but I've managed to track it to this point now. Any help would be appreciated as it's driving me insane!

[Chosen-select displaying multiple values from an array with one value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59068973/chosen-select-displaying-multiple-values-from-an-array-with-one-value)

UPDATE:

I've realised if I do this:

```
array[0] = "Campus Wired Network"
$('.chosen-select').val(array[0]).trigger('chosen:updated');
```

But if I just call:

```
$('.chosen-select').val(array[0]).trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Then it displays twice.... :/

The console.log shows
     `Campus Wired Network`

I must be missing something really obvious :(

Comment: Just to get the question out of the way.  What is the value of `array[0]` if you console log it?

Comment: Campus Wired Network - only the once - the length of the array is also 1

Comment: In the code you posted yesterday, you call `$('.chosen-select').val(newArray).trigger('chosen:updated');` two times in the success callback.

Comment: @trace I've paired the code back to the point of just trying to update the first array value. I've also updated the question as I've just realised I think it must be something wrong with my data structure! Even though it's ouputting Campus Wired Network, it's doing it twice?

Comment: Your dom selector is querying a class. Is it possible that it occurs in the dom more than once?